# Determinant of a generalization of Vandermonde matrix is nonzero

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $p\geq 1$ and $k\geq 0$ be integers. Consider the set $P \subset \mathbb{Z}_+^p$ of all $\alpha = (a_1,\dots,a_p) \in \mathbb{Z}^p_+$ such that $|\alpha| = a_1+\dots+a_p \leq k$. Enumerate $P = \{ \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_l \}$. Let $$M_{p,k} = \left (\alpha_i^{\alpha_j} \right )_{i,j=1}^l$$ be the matrix with index $(i,j)$ equal to $$\alpha_i^{\alpha_j} : = a_{i,1}^{a_{j,1}} \cdots a_{i,p}^{a_{j,p}} ,$$
where $\alpha_s=(a_{s,1},\dots,a_{s,p})$ for each $s = 1,\dots,l$.

I want to prove that the determinant of $M_{p,k}$ is nonzero. I tried some examples, and it worked, but I can't find a way to prove it in general.

When $p=1$ and the order is the natural order of the integers, we have that $$
M_{1,k} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & 2  & 4 &\cdots  & 2^k \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & k & k^2 & \cdots & k^k \end{bmatrix}.$$ Thus, in a sense, that determinant is a generalization of the Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix this, but it is confusing that you use the notation $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_p$ for the entries of $\alpha \in \Bbb Z_+^p$ in the beginning of your question and later use $\alpha_i$ to denote an element in $\Bbb Z_+^p$.

Comment: Thank you, Ben. I fixed that.